# mulitple plot at the same position on mayavi

Tags: python, plot, mayavi

I'm trying to plot this "F" vector function in R3. Together with the Sphere centered at origin of radius Pi/2.

- I do not understand why my vectors and my sphere are not at the same position.
- I do not understand mlab.axes "axes visibility", I just would like to display the usual x,y,z axes.

Sorry if it is obvious to some, but I went through the standard documentation, few examples and google searches for a few hours, and I'm still clueless.

[image: The function]

My current Mayavi Result and Code:

[image: Mayavi Results]

```
import numpy as np
from mayavi import mlab


# Functions
def h(t):
    return np.exp(-1/t) * (1/np.cos(t))


def F(x, y, z):
    norm = np.linalg.norm([x, y, z])
    h_norm = (h(norm)/norm)
    return [x*h_norm, y*h_norm, z*h_norm]


# Vectors
x, y, z = np.meshgrid(np.arange(-2, 2, 0.5),
                      np.arange(-2, 2, 0.5),
                      np.arange(-2, 2, 0.5))

u, v, w = F(x, y, z)

src = mlab.pipeline.vector_field(u, v, w)
mlab.pipeline.vectors(src, mask_points=20, scale_factor=.5)

# Ball
dphi, dtheta = np.pi/250.0, np.pi/250.0
[phi, theta] = np.mgrid[0:2*np.pi:dphi,
                        0:np.pi:dtheta]
r = np.pi / 2

x2 = r*np.sin(theta)*np.cos(phi)
y2 = r*np.sin(theta)*np.sin(phi)
z2 = r*np.cos(theta)

s = mlab.mesh(x2, y2, z2)

#mlab.axes(x_axis_visibility=True, y_axis_visibility=True)

# View it all.

mlab.outline()
mlab.show()
```